# ScrollView's scroll vs uipageviewcontroller slide

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

My question is similar to: [UIScrollView cancels UIPageViewController gestures when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241736/uiscrollview-cancels-uipageviewcontroller-gestures-when-scrolling) but it still doesn't have answer. I have a uipageviewcontroller to display a pdf, each controller is a pdf page... each controller has a scroll view which displays the pdf page so the user can scroll or zoom in the page. The problem is that the "drag" is first "catched" by the pageviewcontroller (changing page), even if it is a vertical drag. I want to detect if the pageviewcontroller is dragging vetical(to scroll vertically in page), meaning the scroll "catchs" any drag gesture from there. Right now I have to double tap (zoom) or do a zoom with 2 fingers to tell my app that I want the scroll view to "catch" the drag gestures (to make it a `first responder` or something like that maybe). In other words, I want to always scroll as a priority over changing page. Is this posible? please help.

Comment: i used [currentPDFScroll becomeFirstResponder]; but doesn't work either

Comment: actually i found my way around, by fixing other bug... I wanted to start with a zoom greater than 1 which fits the pdf page width, after this the vertical drag are actually catched by the scroll view, so this is no longer a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`UIGestureRecognizer` class has possibility to set dependencies on other gesture recognisers by using [requireGestureRecognizerToFail:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail%3a) method.
In your case this method could be used in such way:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerForFail in pageController.gestureRecognizers) {
    for (PDFController *pdfController in pdfControllers) {
        for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in pdfController.scrollView.gestureRecognizers) {
            [gestureRecognizerForFail requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gestureRecognizer];
        }
    }
}
```

where `PDFController` is your class that contains scrollView that should be scrolled in higher priority then page controller.