# Swift UITableView Swipe During Scroll Animation

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, scrollview, gesture

I've looked around and tried everything I can think of sort of subclassing TableView, but I think I'm missing something. I have a TableView with entries that I can swipe left and right on, and everything works fine. However, if:

1) I start (vertically) scrolling a little bit, and then swipe, the `TableView`'s superclass, `ScrollView`, seems to block the swipe from my `TableViewCell`.

2) I stop scrolling, but the animation hasn't *fully* stopped, the swipe is *still* blocked from the `TableViewCell`.

How can I allow my swipe to get passed through to my `TableViewCell`, regardless of the vertical scroll?

Comment: Your problem is that the main `scrollView` (the `tableView`) is still actively engaged with a gesture, so another similar gesture is not being recognized (and actually blocked). Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241736/uiscrollview-cancels-uipageviewcontroller-gestures-when-scrolling?rq=1 which discusses this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3**

I fixed this basically by doing what was suggested in this thread: [Tell ScrollView to Scroll after other pan gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180613/tell-scrollview-to-scroll-after-other-pan-gesture?lq=1)

Below is code that should enable someone else that comes across this thread to *scroll in a table view, and be able to swipe, without having to deal with the table view's pan gesture recognizer blocking the swipe due to the mere hint of vertical motion*.

Hope it helps someone.

So (inside a `UITableViewController` -- non--essential code emitted):

```
    var lsgr : UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.lsgr = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didSwipeLeft:")
        self.lsgr.direction = .Left
        self.lsgr.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.lsgr.delegate = self
    }

    func didSwipeLeft(leftSwipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        var ip = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(leftSwipe.locationOfTouch(0,inView: self.tableView))
        print("swipe left - "+String(ip!.row))
    }
```